# best way to hide/show dynamically added content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am trying to create a working way to show/collapse content that is added dynamically. I am using rel tags to detect which index and description size that should be shown. I have included my example to make my question easier to understand. However, my solution does not work as it ends up showing the "full" text version only.

Here is the link to my example

http://jsfiddle.net/rowej/z5wTj/15/

or code is below

HTML:

```
<span id="11_fulltext" rel="11"><p> full text area </p>
  <a href="#" class="switch" rel="big">Toggle</a>
</span>

<span id="11_smalltext" rel="11">
  <p> small text area</p>
  <a href="#" class="switch" rel="small">Toggle</a>
</span>
```

Jquery (onload):

```
$(".switch").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var index=$(this).closest('span').attr('rel');
  var bigorsmall=$(this).attr('rel');

  alert(index+bigorsmall);
  if(bigorsmall="big"){
    $('#'+index+'_fulltext').hide();
    $('#'+index+'_smalltext').show();    
  }

  if(bigorsmall="small"){
    $('#'+index+'_smalltext').hide();  
    $('#'+index+'_fulltext').show();
  }
});
```

Is using rel tags like this ok?
Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you code,

`if(bigorsmall="big"){`

Will always be truthy (you are missing an extra = sign)

`if(bigorsmall=="big"){`

same for second part

`if(bigorsmall="small"){` should be `if(bigorsmall=="small"){`

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier than you think. [Here is an updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/z5wTj/21/)

**HTML:**

```
<span>
    <p>full text area</p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="switch">Toggle</a>
</span>
<span>
    <p>small text area</p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="switch">Toggle</a>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.switch', function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

This solution is compatible with dynamically adding new text areas of that format. Using `$(document).on('click', '.switch'` allows you to catch clicks from events on elements created after the listener was attached. [See jQuery `.on()` docs.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Edit:** updated the fiddle to dynamically create new toggleable content blocks

Comment: thanks for your help and I see how this could be used, but not 100% what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do is exactly what the new HTML 5 data attributes are meant for.  You can append to an element like this:

```
<a href="#" class="switch" data-size="big">Toggle</a>
```

And access it like this:

```
var bigorsmall=$(this).data('size');
```

This approach should still work using JQuery even if you have an older browser I believe, not 100% sure though.

Change this:

```
if(bigorsmall="big"){
if(bigorsmall="small"){
```

To this as @Aknosis mentioned, as well as this:

```
if(bigorsmall=="big"){
if(bigorsmall=="small"){
```

You need double equals for comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Small and Big seem to be styling like stuff so I would just add a class for it.

You should use the [`data-attributes`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml):

```
<span id="11_fulltext" data-index="11"><p> full text area </p>
    <a href="#" class="switch big">Toggle</a>
</span>
<span id="11_smalltext" data-index="11">
    <p> small text area</p>
    <a href="#" class="switch small">Toggle</a>
</span>
```

And you can retrieve the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute by doing:

```
$(element).data('index');
```

PS

This isn't going to work as expected:

```
if(bigorsmall="big"){
```

It should be:

```
if(bigorsmall=="big"){
```

What you would get is something like:

```
$(".switch").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this);

    var index = a.closest('span').data('index');

    if(a.hasClass('big')) {
      $('#'+index+'_fulltext').hide(); // is an id starting with a number valid???
      $('#'+index+'_smalltext').show();    
    } else {
      $('#'+index+'_smalltext').hide();  
      $('#'+index+'_fulltext').show();
    }
});
```